# How to create chaining tasks

Tags: c#, async-await, task-parallel-library

I want to create a chaining logic with for schedule.

1. Access token will get every 1 hour.
2. If access token get success, Get the version
3. But access token will continue if version.HasNextVersion false.

   ```
   public async Task<string> GetAccessToken(){
     /// getting token from server as async.
   }

   public async Task<string> GetVersions(string token){
       // Web request as async
       var version = await GetVersionsFromServer(token); 

      // if there are any other version after this version, I will get the next
       if(version.HasNextVersion) 
          await GetVersions();
   }

   string Main(){

    var accessToken = GetAccessToken().Wait();

    var version =  GetVersions(string token).Wait();

   }
   ```

I am new at asynchrşnous operations and Task library. Is this possible?

Comment: `await` already chains the tasks. It doesn't make anything run asynchronously. It *awaits* for an already asynchronous operation to finish and then continues execution with the code right after the asynchronous operation, ie it chains it

Comment: BTW in C# 7.2 you can define an `async Task Main()` method and avoid the `.Wait()` calls. In previous versions create a separate method that contains anything that requires `async` and use `.Wait()` only once

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`await` already chains the tasks. It doesn't make anything run asynchronously. It awaits for an already asynchronous operation to finish and then continues execution with the code right after the asynchronous operation.

If the actual question is `how do I await in Main`, in C# 7.1 you can have an `async Task Main()` signature, eg:

```
public static async Task Main(string[] args)
{

   var accessToken = await GetAccessToken();
   var version =  await GetVersions(string token);
}
```

If you have Visual Studio 2017 with one of the latest updates you can simply change your language version from the Project Properties, Build page. The language options can be accessed from the Advanced button at the bottom of the page.

This is described in detail [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-7-1#async-main) and [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mazhou/2017/05/30/c-7-series-part-2-async-main/)

In previous versions you'll have to extract all async code to a separate method and use `.Wait()` only once :

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    InnerMain(args).Wait();
}

private static async Task InnerMain(string[] args)
{
   var accessToken = await GetAccessToken();
   var version =  await GetVersions(string token);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Proper way (go async all the way except the entry point):

```
public async Task<string> GetAccessToken(){
    return "token";
}

public async Task<string> GetVersions(string token){
    var version = await GetVersionsFromServer(token); 

    if(version.HasNextVersion) 
       version = await GetVersions();

   // you need to return something!
   return version;
}

private async Task DoWork() {
  var accessToken = await GetAccessToken();
  var version =  await GetVersions(accessToken);
}

string Main(){
 DoWork().Wait();
}
```

Otherwise you can use `.Result` instead of `.Wait()` on a `Task` to block and wait for the result. Watchout for thread locks.